# Styled component styles are not being shown inside the style tag in Gatsby site

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I have my [portfolio](https://5f10b041b5a4d60007159320--hardcore-payne-e855ba.netlify.app/) in which the styles are not being added to the styles tag. On further inspection, I saw that I can see the styles when I view the page source.
[image: Page Source]


but when I open Chrome Dev Tools I do not see the styles being injected.
[image: Dev Tools].


Any help will be appreciated. A live demo can be seen [here](https://5f10b041b5a4d60007159320--hardcore-payne-e855ba.netlify.app/) and the repo can be found [here](https://github.com/manan30/portfolio-v2)

Comment: What is the problem with the demo link you shared? Looks like it's working.

Comment: If you open up dev tools and check the `<styles>` tag is empty

Answer (score 0):

In production, styled-components injects styles using CSSOM api, while Chrome DevTools doesn't support handle it.

You can get more discussions via https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=387952

In development, everything is ok.